# React: Redirect withRouter causes Warning: React does not recognize the `staticContext` prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap4-modal

I have a Modal from React Bootstrap. I want to redirect it using `withRouter` to a "reports" page after the client has run (`onSubmit`) a POST request to an API. It all works fine but I keep getting a warning:

```
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `staticContext` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `staticcontext` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

Below is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, FormFile, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import * as simulator from "../api/simulatorAPI";
import Body from "../api/model/body.json";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function RunSimsModal(props) {
  const [numberofSims, setNumberOfSims] = useState("");
  const [simName, setSimName] = useState("");

const runSims = event => {
    console.log("run simulations");
    simulator.runSim(
      Body.clientId,
      simName,
      numberofSims
    );
    props.history.push("/reports");
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      {...props}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
          Run Simulations
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>

      <Modal.Body>
        <h4>Run Sims</h4>

        <Form onSubmit={runSims}>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Label>Number Of Simulations</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              required
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter number of sims"
              value={numberofSims}
              onChange={e => setNumberOfSims(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Label>Simulation Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              required
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter simulation name"
              value={simName}
              onChange={e => setSimName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Button type="submit">Run</Button>
        </Form>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default withRouter(RunSimsModal);
```

And here is my NavigationBar.js :

```
import React from "react";
import { Nav, Navbar, Form, FormControl, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import styled from "styled-components";
import RunSimsModal from "./RunSimsModal";

const Styles = styled.div`
  .navbar {
    background-color: #222;
  }
  a,
  .navbar-nav,
  .navbar-light .nav-link {
    color: #9fffcb;
    &:hover {
      color: white;
    }
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #9fffcb;
    &:hover {
      color: white;
    }
  }
  .form-center {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 55%;
    right: 25%;
  }
`;
export const NavigationBar = function () {
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);
  return <Styles>
    <Navbar expand="lg" fixed ="top">
      <Navbar.Brand href="/">Decade3</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Form className="form-center">
        <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="" />
      </Form>
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="ml-auto">
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)} >Run Sims</Button>{' '}
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>

    <RunSimsModal show={modalShow} onHide={() => setModalShow(false)} />
  </Styles>
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is? I'm fairly new to React so am still working out the core concepts as I go along.

Comment: Hi @ElAoutarHamza I read that post before this, but I didn't really understand it...

Comment: Can you try this: `function RunSimsModal({ staticContext, ...props })`

Comment: Thanks @devserkan it looks to have worked!

Comment: Nice :) Then, let me vote to close this since there is already an answer as @ElAoutarHamza shared. I just helped a little bit :)